# How to target specific div with Blazor components?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-component

I have a `top-row` div a follows:

```
   <div class="top-row px-3">
      <b>App:<i>Title</i></b>

      <!-- wait for it ... -->
      <div class="menu">
         Menu Bar Here
      </div>

   </div>
```

I am going to have several `MenuBar` components that will swap out in the div class `menu` *with a button click*.  How do I target that div with a Blazor component?

**Update**
I think I found a solution by [Chris Sainty](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/).

**Edit**
To clarify what I intend to accomplish:

I have 2 components:

- `<MenuBar1 />`
- `<MenuBar2 />`

Both contain different html to construct a simple menu bar. I have navigational links that, when clicked, will raise the `onClick` event.

How, when the link is clicked, can I swap out the *MenuBar* components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blazor doesn't use Javascript strategy.
To do that you have to mix HTML with code.

```
<div class="top-row px-3">
    <b>App:<i>Title</i></b>
    <!-- wait for it ... -->
    <div class="menu">
        @if (Version == "v1")
        {
            <p>version 1</p>
        }
        else if (Version == "v2")
        {
            <p>version 2</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

For dynamic menu add a file in shared folder.
The file name = the class name
For example **MenuButton**.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager navManager
<button @onclick="(e)=>navManager.NavigateTo(route)">@(label)</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string label { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string route { get; set; }
}
```

To consume this componant

```
<div class="top-row px-3">
    <b>App:<i>Title</i></b>
    <!-- wait for it ... -->
    <div class="menu">
        <MenuButton label="Choice 1" route="/route1" />
        <MenuButton label="Choice 2" route="/route2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the cause of the change. This is a useful answer for a static solution ... don't erase it. Can you add how to do this with a button click?

Comment: I'm interested in seeing what solution you come up with possibly with the link I reference in my question.

Comment: I used a combination of your answer and what Chris Sainty does on his. I will show my work shortly. In all fairness, I was still not clear on what my intentions were. I will again edit the question to fully clarify what I intended to accomplish.